# override react native style

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I want to override some sub-component of style in react native.like -
I have created an style `CircleShapeView`

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      CircleShapeView: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 50/2,
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    },
    });
```

I want change `backgroundColor` ,when i am usins this style. some thing like this.

```
<Image
style={backgroundColor: "#fff", styles.CircleShapeView}                   
...
/>
```

What is right way to do it?

Comment: Did you try
`<Image
  style={{ ...styles.CircleShapeView, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
...
/>`

Comment: @Adolfo This does not work, below answer worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To override the backgroundColor, you could just do this:

```
<Image
style={[ styles.CircleShapeView, { backgroundColor: "#fff" } ]}                   
...
/>
```

A more flexible way of overriding style would be to pass an additional style prop to your subcomponent.

You would call your subcomponent like that:

```
<Subcomponent passedStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }} />
```

Apply passed style to your image:

```
<Image
style={[ styles.CircleShapeView, this.props.passedStyle ]}                   
...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers here, make sure that you are specifying the inherited props style AFTER the style on the component you are trying to override.

Example:
Do this:

```
<Image
   style={[ styles.CircleShapeView, this.props.passedStyle ]}                   
   ...
/>
```

Not this:

```
<Image
   style={[ this.props.passedStyle, styles.CircleShapeView ]}                   
   ...
/>
```

The second example will NOT override the style on the component.